# osx cancel startup applications from login window

Tags: macos

I am positive there is some official Apple documentation and link for a list of different keys one can press during the login window (not the startup) that will do some different action. In particular I am looking for the one that would cancel the reopening of applications, even if at shutdown one said to reopened them. I saw this online the other day, but can't seem to find it again.

Any help is greatly appreacited! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the account you want to login to, enter the password, hit Enter and immediately press and hold the Shift key. You may also hit Shift+Enter once you’ve typed the password, and you will have similar results.